# Specific role can only change status (active/blocked) of any user

Tags: 7, views, users

I've created a views page (holding all users information) for role **ONE**. Now I would like to give permission to that role he can change status (active/blocked) without editing the other fields (email, phone, username etc.) of the users.

I tried with [Editable Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/editablefields) module but it doesn't provide "editable formatter" in Users views field so it won't work for user's built-in field.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the question,

> I would like to give permission to that role he can change status (active/blocked) without editing the other fields...

I've done it without giving permission (Administer users) to role **ONE**.

I had to do configurations between tree modules [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag), [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) and [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules). I created `new flag`, `get flag in views using relationship` and the `add two simple rules`. That's all

Let me post the answer, may be someone will need in the future.

- Above mentioned three modules should be enabled with their UIs.

### **Creating Flag**

- Go to `/admin/structure/flags/add`, create a new flag and choose User as **Flag Type**, [example](http://prntscr.com/jag3s8)
- After saving the Flag Type, fill next form [like this](https://prnt.sc/jagdl9), you may choose options as you like.

### **Creating Views**

- Now, create a views page/block as you like with showing [Users](http://prntscr.com/jagfja) category and your all fields you want to show and add a **Relationship** for the flag you just created (in my case it was "[Block User](http://prntscr.com/jagid1)").
- Now, add a new field as **Flag link** in the views and add relationship if its already not and choose [settings](http://prntscr.com/jagmwa)
- Save the views

### **Creating Rule**

We have to add to rules one for block the user and other for activate the user.

**Block User**

- Add a new Rule `/admin/config/workflow/rules/reaction/add` and choose event *"[A user has been flagged, under Block User](http://prntscr.com/jagpb1)"* and save
- Add a condition using "[Data comparison](http://prntscr.com/jagrdx)" and continue
- Add value in data selector for *[flagged-user:status](http://prntscr.com/jagtyx)* and continue
- On next form, choose value as [active](http://prntscr.com/jagv0f) and save
- Now, add an action with [Block User](http://prntscr.com/jagwhp) action and continue and add choose data selector for [flagging-user](http://prntscr.com/jagxgu) and save

**Activate User**

There are same steps to activate users using rules. You just only to change event as *"[A user has been unflagged, under Block User](http://prntscr.com/jagpb1)"*, check the status as blocked instead of [active](http://prntscr.com/jagv0f) and finally add action [Unblock User](http://prntscr.com/jagwhp) instead of Block user.

All done...

Now, go to view the [views](http://prntscr.com/jah1b3) you just created check if it works.

I hope it'll help someone.